# Laravel install database creation failed

Tags: php, laravel, homestead

I am attempting to follow a tutorial to install homestead and laravel.

When I type vagrant provision I get an error

```
default: createdb: database creation failed: ERROR:  database "homestead_box" already exists
```

Even when that database doesn't exist, I tried removing all homestead files and packages and VM but didn't work.

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: I am using the default homestead.yaml , is there a way of completely clear all of homestead and it's settings?

Comment: Isn't this normal? If you SSH in to your VM and do artisan migrate, it should find the database and do the migrations. Of course you'll need to set the database in your .env file first. Then try connecting to the database and see if your migrations are there in the correct database